# Can I assume that class fields are going to be in CPU cache?

Tags: c#, cpu-cache

In C# I always wonder how memory access patterns effects performance of the my application.
For example I have a class that has 5 fields and in a function of that class I access all of them.
So my question is when I access these fields are they going to be already in cache (so I get cache hit) or CPU needs to go add pull that data from RAM (so I get cache miss). And if you have a resource that I can read about this kind of memory management tricks in C# please provide a link.

Comment: why do you need to know that? Where and when an object is stored (there is a stack and a heap), is usually irrelevant. C# - as Java # are **managed** languages, so there's little use in thinking about object adresses and where those are stored. Unless you have some super-ciritical performance-issue I won't care for that at all.

Comment: I am just wondering.

Comment: Yes, you can assume that.  The .NET memory model makes no guarantee that *all* the fields will be cached after you've accessed one of them.  Objects are aligned to 4 in 32-bit code, to 8 in 64-bit code and an L1 cache line is 64 bytes.  So while 5 fields are likely to fit in one cache line, if you're unlucky then it takes two.  Nothing you can do about that, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't worry about it. The compiler writers and CPU designers are smart and typically ensures the cache is well used.

In practice a class will store all fields one after each other. And since you always fetch a full cache-line from memory at a time, it is likely that all fields will be fetched and cached from a single memory load.

Where it *can* matter is if you have lots of small objects that may be stored at different places in memory. For example when using linked lists to store small objects. See Bjarne Stroustrup lecture  [Why you should avoid Linked Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo). So some algorithms benefit from using value types and arrays instead of objects. An example would be something like a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation), while it could be implemented with an object for each node, using an single array will save space and ensure all nodes are sequential in memory, and that typically help with cache efficiency.

But only optimize things when there is an actual performance problem, and then make sure to measure the performance first.